# Unable to connect to gerrit in bridge adapter mode

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

I am working with Ubuntu OS on a virtual machine, where I copied the id_rsa.pub generated by ssh-keygen to my web Gerrit account.

When I tried to 'ssh name@gerrit_host -p 29814' while the virtual machine was configured as NAT, it connected easily. (I got the welcome to Gerrit screen).
But, when I tried to do the same thing while the VM is configured as Bridge Adapter, it hung until I got a timeout error.

Since I am working on the Ubuntu OS from remote via ssh, I configured it to work with NAT with port forwarding to allow my ssh connection. But then again, for some reason, I wasn't able to connect to gerrit (timeout error).

I would appreciate if you could assist me with a possible explanation for this behavior and/or a possible solution.

In bridge adapter I can access external internet sites easily from the VM and I can ping the gerrit server. But once I try to ssh it, it hangs. BTW, I can ssh other servers that aren't gerrit.

Attached traceret:

```
$ traceroute gerrit
traceroute to gerrit (172.16.xxx.xxx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.4.0.1 (10.4.0.1)  26.955 ms  26.922 ms  26.887 ms
 2  10.255.255.4 (10.255.255.4)  26.849 ms  26.815 ms  26.769 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Many thanks!

Comment: When the VM is in Bridge mode, can you access the internet (any site!) from within it? If yes, can you provide a tracert from within the VM to the gerrit site?

Comment: @bentz123 it appears you have created two accounts. You should take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts.

Comment: Hey @MariusMatutiae I updated my question with the info you asked about.